# LinkedIn API using asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, api, linkedin-api

I'm making a social platform for my university in asp.net. I need to integrate the LinkedIn API in my site to fetch profiles, their current work and all other relevant information. The profiles should be of people who are associated with my university. I don't know how to use/integrate the LinkedIn API. I have read https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api and http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-api-resource-map but I could not understand how to use it. Please guide me how to use/integrate it.

Comment: Post your best try and the errors you are stuck at.